# Purpose of .dll.so in mono

Tags: mono

Such as `mcs.exe.so`, `mscorlib.dll.so`

What is the purpose of having `.dll.so`?

Can I delete them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are [Mono AOT](http://www.mono-project.com/AOT) precompiled images, used for speeding up application startup. Mono should work without them, but will start a bit slower (as it will have to generate this information instead of loading it from disk).

Answer (score -1):

.so files are libraries in Linux.

When a mono application tries to load a .dll file, mono appends .so to the end and tries to load that.

So no, don't delete them.